# Can we restrict adding our custom React web part to the site collection home page only

Tags: development, spfx, spfx-webparts, administration, app-catalog

I have developed a custom web part using these steps for our SharePoint online communication site:-

```
md spfx-MyModalPopup

cd spfx-MyModalPopup

yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

Chose SharePoint online + React

Then i deploy the App to the SharePoint App Catalog >> then i added the Web Part to the root site collection.

Now can i force this rule for the web part:-

*To only allow the web part to be added inside the current site Home page. so if the current page is not set as the home page for the site to prevent adding the web part..*

can i force such as rule inside the web part?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the webpart's context to determine if the page you're on is the homepage for the web using:

```
    if(this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.isWebWelcomePage as boolean) {
      // Do the stuff
    } else {
      // Render a warning saying this is only for the homepage
    }
```

Comment: when you say to use the WebPart context, can you determine which class/method you are referring to ? thanks

Comment: In SPFx, your webpart class extends `BaseClientSideWebPart` which provides the context and values from that context can be passed as properties or parameters to your render logic. This is true for extensions as well who inherit from their own base classes with context available. So the `this` above refers to your webpart/extension class (same place as your property pane configuration/management). You could write that logic directly in your `public render(): void` method of your webpart or you could pass off the properties to sub components called from that render method.